# Vuetify autocomplete not showing suggestions with more than one search term

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js

When I make a search with Vuetify `<v-autocomplete>` and my API, `mytext` and `myvalue` are correctly updated and displayed in the suggestions only if write a word like `FOO`, if I write a string like `FOO BAR`, then I get the correct result with `console.log(response.data)` in the API call method, but I get nothing in the suggestions of `<v-autocomplete>`.

`<template>`:

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="select"
  :loading="loading"
  :items="items"
  item-text="mytext"
  item-value="myvalue"
  :search-input.sync="search"
  hide-no-data
  hide-details
  label="My Autocomplete"
>
  <template v-slot:item="data">
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title v-html="data.item.mytext"></v-list-item-title>
      <v-list-item-subtitle
        v-html="data.item.myvalue"
      ></v-list-item-subtitle
    ></v-list-item-content>
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

`<script>`:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      select: null,
      loading: false,
      items: [],
      search: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    search(val) {
      console.log('search: ' + val)
      val && val !== this.select && this.query(val)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async query(v) {
      this.loading = true
      await this.$axios
        .get('/api/foo', {
          params: {
            search: this.search
          }
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data)
          this.items = response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading = false
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The `search` variable seems to be linked to the `items` variable.

Comment: change `<template v-slot:item="data">` to `<template v-slot:item=" {data} ">`

Comment: @Mohsen I get this error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply `no-filter` prop to your `v-autocomplete` component.

```
<v-autocomplete
    ...
    no-filter
    ...
>
</v-autocomplete>
```

As written in documentation for this prop:

> Do not apply filtering when searching. Useful when data is being
> filtered server side

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it by adding this prop to `<v-autocomplete>`:

```
:filter="() => true"
```